# Lipsum produces a strange error with the simplest use

Tags: errors, lipsum

The package `lipsum` behaves in a strange way and I can't figure out why. It used to work normally. The problems started suddenly and on all three PC's that I use to code. I tried different compilers, document classes, and different locations of the source file on my disk. I also reinstalled the `lipsum` package using MiKTeX Console's package manager. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Hard to imagine for me how anything might go wrong with that, but here's a snippet of the output I get (note the first five characters, and also that the following text doesn't even start with "Lorem ipsum..."):
[image]

etc. The compilation produces three errors; here's an extract from the .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 21.12.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.10.24)  24 OCT 2022 17:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./02.tex
(02.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\report.cls
Document Class: report 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count183
\c@chapter=\count184
\c@section=\count185
\c@subsection=\count186
\c@subsubsection=\count187
\c@paragraph=\count188
\c@subparagraph=\count189
\c@figure=\count190
\c@table=\count191
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2021-11-22 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-12-14 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count192
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
))
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2021-11-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
Package: lipsum 2019/01/02 v2.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text

(C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.ltd.tex
File: lipsum.ltd.tex 2019/01/02 v2.2 The Lorem ipsum dummy text
))
No file 02.aux.
\openout1 = `02.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> \__xparse_split_argument:nnn 
                                             {1}{-}{1-7}
l.5 \end
        {document}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.
<argument> \???  
                 ! LaTeX cmd Error: Invalid argument {\__int_eval_end: } to ...
l.5 \end
        {document}
If you say, e.g., `\def\a1{...}', then you must always
put `1' after `\a', since control sequence names are
made up of letters only. The macro here has not been
followed by the required stuff, so I'm ignoring it.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_let:D 
l.5 \end
        {document}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

[1

{C:/Users/Martin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
[2] (02.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 671 strings out of 478690
 14547 string characters out of 2854636
 495580 words of memory out of 3000000
 18816 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 53i,5n,63p,198b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10
.pfb>
Output written on 02.pdf (2 pages, 23297 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 14 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

How on earth is this possible? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: it appears you have a new lipsum package with an old latex format, how did you install?

Comment: check in the miktex console in user *and* admin mode if there are updates.

Comment: show the full log, it should be less than 100 lines (it should be 82, but you have errors so it will be a bit longer)

Comment: I just edited the question, now it contains the full log. Thanks for the quick replys.

Comment: as @UlrikeFischer guessed you have 2 tex trees and they are out of sync `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\report.cls`  v `C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/lipsum\lipsum.sty`

Comment: as already said: update. You have files in your user tree C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX and files in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9 and they are not in sync.

Comment: It's amazing I only learned about this issue now and because of such a trivial package. Thanks a lot, next time I am going to read the log file more carefully. Still, I wonder how this could have happened. Is it possible that I installed MiKTeX using the wrong directories (C:\Users\Martin\AppData\Roaming\...) but the Console installs the packages into C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\... (which it does, and I do start it as Admin)?

I guess what I want to ask is what would be the recommended way to sort this out.

Comment: @MrMRm you are the 10000001'st miktex user to fall in to this trap, I don't use miktex but it comes up here so often I could still guess the answer. You can install just as admin. but if you install as admin and user you need to always update both otherwise you will end up with clashes like this,

Comment: you installed miktex in multi user mode. And that means that part of the packages are "for all users" and some are only for you in your user tree. That is not wrong, but it means that you have to do the maintenance (updates) in both modes.

Comment: It helped, now it works fine. Many thanks. One more note: I use WinEdt and always start MiKTeX console using a button there. It automatically starts the Console in the admin mode, not ever giving me the choice. So I didn't even realize the two options were there.